# Installing emacs-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I am new to emacs and I would like to use emacs-rails for editing rhtml files. I have been at it for awhile with no luck. I have followed the directions on this page
http://developer.idapted.com/2009/1/13/install-and-config-emacs-for-rails

I get an error that Symbol's value as variable is void "/.emacs.d/rails"

This just seems to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am on ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message, my guess is you have something like:

```
(load /.emacs.d/rails)
```

where you should have that in quotes:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/rails")
```

Or, perhaps you're using `require`, but either way, you've likely forgotten quotes around something.

Ah, I took a look at the link you provided, the quotes are wrong.  The double quotes should both be the regular " type, not the `` type.

i.e. the link points to:

```
``~/.emacs.d/rails"
```

but what you really need is

```
"~/.emacs.d/rails"
```

Comment: The tilda should be ok, can you post the code you added to your .emacs?